# Find the values of the minimum and maximum of the function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, optimization

I need to find extremums of this function:
$f(x_{1}, x_{2}, ....,x_{n}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{i}^{k}$, where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{i}=a, a>0, k>0,x_{i} \geq 0$

How to solve this problem? I don't understand how to apply Lagrange here

Comment: Can you show what you got when you applied method of Lagrange Multipiers ? Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but should i apply lagrange to this kind of functions at all? i haven't found any examples of that

Comment: The expression $f(x_1, x_2, …, x_n) = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} x_i^k$ makes absolutely no sense. You have used $n$ twice and what are $x_i$ if $i>n$?

Comment: @Shaqinho $x_{n+1}$

Comment: What don't you understand about Lagrange ? This is a standard case, optimization under equality constraint.